# WPF UserControl Dependency Property value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have the following problem: I made a UserControl in WPF which has an AgreementID property. I need to call this UserControl in another UserControl, and I need to give an AgreementID with it when I call it. Now I made a DependencyProperty in the first UserControl, but it does not work.

This is the code of my first UserControl:

```
public partial class UC1001_AgreementDetails_View : UserControl
    {

        private UC1001_ActiveAgreementContract _contract;
        private int _agreementID;

        public int AgreementID
        {
            get { return _agreementID; }
            set { _agreementID = value; }
        }

        public UC1001_AgreementDetails_View()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       public static readonly DependencyProperty AgreementIDProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("AgreementID", typeof(int), typeof(UC1001_AgreementDetails_View), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

This is the XAML where I call previous UserControl:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <!--<Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Months[9].AgreementID}"/>-->
            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding Months[9].AgreementID}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="DataGridCell.ToolTip">
                 <Setter.Value>
                     <my:UC1001_AgreementDetails_View Background="#FFF" Opacity="0.88" AgreementID="{Binding Months[9].AgreementID}"/>
                 </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
```

So I want to pas the AgreementID of that month onto the first UserControl, but when I check it, the passed value is always 0, but it should be 3. I checked the Months[9].AgreementID value and it was 3 indeed. So I get the right value in the binding, but it's not passing through right.

I hope my problem is a bit clear to you, additional information can be given if wanted!

Comment: Take a look at MVVM; this would allow you to store your data within a common ViewModel which could be shared amongst your Views (UserControls). More often then not a UserControl is a carryover from WinForms thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining the Property facade for the Dependency Property wrong. In your property definition, you need to work on the Dependency Property and set and return its value:

```
public int AgreementID
{
    get { return (int) GetValue(AgreementIDProperty ); }
    set { SetValue(AgreementIDProperty, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As already indicated, your property wrapper should be calling `GetValue` and `SetValue` on the dependency property (and you can dispense with the backing field). However, it is worth pointing out that the wrapper property will be bypassed when the `DependencyProperty` is set directly in XAML or from a declarative `Binding`. So if you actually checked the value of the `DependencyProperty` itself using `GetValue` then you would see that the value **was** actually being set by your `Binding`. It's the retrieval of the property value via your wrapper in procedural code that's failing since it's not accessing the `DependencyProperty`.